# Слайдер переходящий в блоки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Добрый день, мне нужна помощь ваша
Допустим у меня есть 10 div для слайдера и они размещены горизонтально ,а будет видно 5 div, а при следующем переходе слайдов следующие 5 div. Но когда разрешение экрана есть меньше 920px например мне нужно что бы эти все блоки был видны и били горизонтально размещены, то есть нужно при переходе на 920px убирать слайдер...
Кто может помочь с такой проблемой? Может существуют такие слайдеры?

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Видел такой слайдер но не могу сообразить как сделать при < 920px что бы блоки были вертикальные и фактически убрался слайдер?

Comment: Добавляете каждый див в слайд, и устанавливаете на определенные брекпоинты количество слайдов

Answer (score 2):

Например:

Есть 10 слайдов, прокручиваются по 5. 
Но когда разрешение экрана есть меньше 920px (для примера просто привела не 920, а 520px), эти все блоки видны и горизонтально размещены (из вопроса).

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
  var width = $(document).width();
  
  if (width < 520) {
    $('.slider').slick('unslick');
  } else {
    $('.slider').not('.slick-initialized').slick({  
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 5,
      infinite: true,
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.slider>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  padding: .5rem;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 520px) {
  .slider>div {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .slick-slide {
    padding: .5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ccc/fff&text=images-1" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ccc/fff&text=images-2" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ccc/fff&text=images-3" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ccc/fff&text=images-4" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ccc/fff&text=images-5" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ccc/fff&text=images-6" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ccc/fff&text=images-7" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ccc/fff&text=images-8" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ccc/fff&text=images-9" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ccc/fff&text=images-10" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

При меньше необходимого разрешения - `$('.slider').slick('unslick');` иначе - инициализируем. `.not('.slick-initialized')` - честно признаюсь не объясню что значит, но решает проблемы с ошибками при ресайзе окна со слайдером.

P.S: стили только для наглядности.